# Overridden method of Custom Collection View Cell does not invoke

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom collection view cell: **BaseCollectionViewCell** and I extended that class and yielded **PastMonth** **CurrentMonth** **FutureMonth** sub classes. However, when I run the application, their supposed overridden method -setView- does not work.

Here is delegate method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == self.currentIndex && self.currentIndex != 0) {
    AnotherExampleCollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AnotherExampleCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
    }
    int typeOfMonth = [self findTypeOfMonth:(int)indexPath.row birthDate:self.birthDate];
    switch (typeOfMonth) {
        case 0: {
        PastMonth* cell = (PastMonth*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BaseCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setView];
        return cell;
    }
        case 1:{
        CurrentMonth* cell = (CurrentMonth*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BaseCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setView];
        return cell;
    }
        default:{
        FutureMonth* cell = (FutureMonth*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BaseCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setView];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

}

Here is BaseCollectionViewCell.h and .m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BaseCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *coverView;

-(void) setView;
@end



#import "BaseCollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation BaseCollectionViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
}

-(void) setView{
   NSLog(@"asdasd");
}
@end
```

Here is the CurrentMonth.m: (I did not put other files since they are almost identical):

```
#import "BaseCollectionViewCell.h"
@interface CurrentMonth : BaseCollectionViewCell
-(void) setView;
@end

#import "CurrentMonth.h"

@implementation CurrentMonth

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during            animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
}
*/
-(void) setView{
    self.coverView.hidden = YES;
    [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
@end
```

Why, for instance, setView of CurrentMonth is not called and instead BaseCollectionViewCell's setView method is called?

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you should use NSStringFromClass([self class]) to check class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the proper class for each cell identifier using `registerClass`

[self.collectionView registerClass:[CurrentMonth class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CurrentMonthCollectionViewCell"];

Similarly for other classes you need to do this.

From Apple documentation:

> You typically do not create instances of this class yourself. Instead,
>   you register your specific cell subclass (or a nib file containing a
>   configured instance of your class) with the collection view object.
>   When you want a new instance of your cell class, call the
>   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: method of the
>   collection view object to retrieve one.

Are you sure you are doing this?

Alternatively if your cells are in a xib you have to set the appropriate custom class for the cell in the xib

Comment: PastMonth,CurrentMonth and FutureMonth are not in xib form. Only their base class are in xib form. I cannot set their identifier since they don't have xib, can I set their identifier programmatically?

Comment: Yes, you can use registerClass as mentioned in my original answer. That should work. If not then duplicate the xib and set the custom class in each xib to the corresponding collection view class and then use registerNib method instead of registerClass. Don't use both of them at the same time. Its one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
CurrentMonth* cell = (CurrentMonth*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BaseCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This will return BaseCollectionViewCell object that's why base class method is getting called.

You might have to create the different custom cell class which could have common base class.

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: {
      PastMonth* cell = (PastMonth*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PastMonthCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      [cell setView];
      return cell;
    }
    case 1:{
      CurrentMonth* cell = (CurrentMonth*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CurrentMonthCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      [cell setView];
      return cell;
    }
    default:{
      FutureMonth* cell = (FutureMonth*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FutureMonthCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      [cell setView];
      return cell;
    }
  }
```

Then you can add the common business logic in BaseCollectionViewCell.

Comment: Actually, the problem is to give an identifier to them. Since they do not have xib, I cannot place their identifier.